# Combining postgres databases from dumps

Tags: postgresql

Is there a recommended way of combining similar postgres databases?

Suppose I have a production database, running on the server, being updated constantly.
I also have a development/testing database, based on a dump of the production database at some previous point in time. The development and production databases are similar, but the development database may have new columns, tables or schemas added to hold functionality enhancements. Likewise the development database has live data continuously being added.

If I have pg_dump output for both databases, how do I combine them so that:
 - All tables, columns and schema from one database are present in the updated database
 - All data from both databases is present in the updated database, without duplicates

Any advice would be appreciated!